# how to set text in another app for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Is it possible for an app to

1. Detect whether the last app used by user is WhatsApp.
2. Open WhatsApp and set text.
3. Set text directly in the opened conversation.

Comment: Is this for a jailbroken or non-jailbroken device?

Comment: non jail broken. which is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you can not access the app history.
2. Yes, you can using url-schemes. Read Whats App's [documentation](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013).
3. See 2

Comment: @twb you got to add the parameter text: `whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!`

Comment: miscommunication. what I meant is user chat with friendA, press home, access my app, which then set a text in friendA (last opened conversation)

Comment: That's not possible. According to the Whats App docs, a contact picker shows up.

Comment: Absolutely. WhatsApp has to support it. E.g. they could make WhatsApp so that if you set parameter `abid` to current the text goes to the current user. You could contact WhatsApp as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Simply No.

1. You cant access the user history.
2. You cant open another app within another app.
3. You cant access another app.

Comment: my intention is not to open other app from my app. maybe copy a text to clipboard, open the other app, and set the text. similar to social sharing without picking the user in whatsapp but the last/current opened conversation.